# VS c++ compile template with member function pointers with error

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, delegates

The code like this:

```
template<class hostClassType, typename returnType, typename ...argumentType>
class Delegate
{
public:
    typedef returnType (hostClassType::*ClassFunctionType)(argumentType...);

    Delegate(hostClassType* obj, ClassFunctionType func)
    {
        m_HostObject = obj;
        m_ClassFunction = func;
    }

private:
    hostClassType* m_HostObject;
    ClassFunctionType m_ClassFunction;
}
```

Visual Studio 2019 compile it with error:

> Error C2825: 'hostClassType': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'

Tried with `<typename hostClassType>` and `<class hostClassType>` in the template. none of them works. Does anyone know what is the problem with the code?

Thank you very much

Comment: Compile fine [here](https://godbolt.org/z/kbFTWW)

Comment: Not able to reproduce! :/

Comment: You are missing a `;` after the class definition's final `}`.

Comment: Missed when i type the code here. in the code compiled, the ; exists. Thanks for the comments

Comment: Thanks all people to help on this problem. I found the solution. This error is not caused by this file. Actually, the code to use this class put void as the hostClassType. Modified to put a class in the code using this class solved this problem.